# Save streaming data to a WAV file using NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I want to save the incoming stream data to a WAV file on my hard disk drive. How can I change the code below to be able to record the stream into a valid WAV file?

From the demo [here](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a2092ffde43a#NAudioDemo/Mp3StreamingDemo/MP3StreamingPanel.cs):

```
private void StreamMP3(object state)
{
    this.fullyDownloaded = false;
    string url = (string)state;
    webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    try
    {
        resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch(WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Status != WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
        {
            ShowError(e.Message);
        }
        return;
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384 * 4]; // Needs to be big enough to hold a decompressed frame

    IMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor = null;
    try
    {
        using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var readFullyStream = new ReadFullyStream(responseStream);
            do
            {
                if (bufferedWaveProvider != null &&
                    bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes <
                      bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 4)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Buffer getting full, taking a break");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                else
                {
                    Mp3Frame frame = null;
                    try
                    {
                        frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(readFullyStream);
                    }
                    catch (EndOfStreamException)
                    {
                        this.fullyDownloaded = true;

                        // Reached the end of the MP3 file / stream
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (WebException)
                    {
                        // Probably we have aborted download from the GUI thread
                        break;
                    }
                    if (decompressor == null)
                    {
                        // I don't think these details matter too much - just help ACM select the right codec.
                        // However, the buffered provider doesn't know what sample rate it is working at
                        // until we have a frame.
                        WaveFormat waveFormat = new Mp3WaveFormat(
                                                  frame.SampleRate,
                                                  frame.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2,
                                                  frame.FrameLength,
                                                  frame.BitRate);
                        decompressor = new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(waveFormat);
                        this.bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
                        this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20); // Allow us to get well ahead of ourselves
                        //this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration = 250;
                    }
                    int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
                    //Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Decompressed a frame {0}", decompressed));
                    bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
                }

            } while (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped);

            Debug.WriteLine("Exiting");
            // I was doing this in a finally block, but for some reason
            // we are hanging on response stream .Dispose, so we never get there.
            decompressor.Dispose();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (decompressor != null)
        {
            decompressor.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't take that particular approach to saving to disk. It's a bit too hands-on, because it has to deal with playing back at the right rate. Just buffer up the response, and then wrap it in an `Mp3FileReader` stream and use `WaveFileWriter` to write the WAV file:

```
MemoryStream mp3Buffered = new MemoryStream();
using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        mp3Buffered.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}

mp3Buffered.Position = 0;
using (var mp3Stream = new Mp3FileReader(mp3Buffered))
{    
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("file.wav", mp3Stream);
}
```

That does, of course, assume that your MP3 file's wave format is compatible with WAV and in particular, your WAV player. If it isn't, you'll need to inject and add a `WaveFormatConversion` stream as well.

Comment: hi, the mp3Stream does not has a method called CopyTo!!

Comment: I guess you're using .NET 3.5 or older then. There's actually an even easier way, anyway, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank MattW for your help, still, is there a way to edit the code above in order to save the streaming file into a valid wav ?...

The code returned an exception: This stream does not support seek operations. which is just what you told me ..

Comment: Ah, that's actually a different error. That's what the ReadFullyStream in your sample code was for, another answer update.

Comment: thanks again for your help ...getting near ..still having exceptions..now with the long Poistion it says Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Comment: Yeah, I expected their ReadFullyStream implementation to do more. It still doesn't support seek, which the Mp3FileReader needs. It would definitely be possible to write a buffering stream that did allow seek, but for now I'll just make my answer stash the entire mp3 in a MemoryStream and use that.

Comment: @lebhero Give that a whirl.

Comment: emmm..only 1 problem: the  public static void CreateWaveFile(string filename, IWaveProvider sourceProvider) wants a IWaveProvider and not a memorystream

Comment: Careless of me, of course I should've been saving the response directly and then feeding that into the mp3 reader. Updated yet again ;)

Comment: Great...one question now...i know the problem with the position..but is there a way to save as soon as data received ?? this should save directly to wav file and not into a memorystream cause i want to save live radio streams ...and this will only write the file when the stream stops --> while (bytesRead > 0) endless ??

Comment: Remember how I said it would be possible to write a buffering stream that allowed seek? That's what you'd need to do. You'd also need to study the Mp3FileReader code to see when it became safe to drop old data. It looks to me at first glance like _probably_ you'd only need to buffer up to the first set of Position, and then once you'd read past the end of the buffer again you could drop the buffer and just read the input stream. Or you could look into providing WaveFileWriter with data a frame at a time and go back to having a loop similar to the one in your sample code.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help.. i will give it a try..i can write the file directly in mp3 file ..i just read the frame and write it to a file ...but it will also be egreat if i could just write the decompressed wav file ...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line to save to `MemoryStream` :

```
mp3Buffered.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
```

Saving stream to file is described in MattW's answer.

Comment: yes, but be aware that wave files are little endian while streamed audio (RTP) is big endian.