# In C#, how to make wav form file?

Tags: c#, audio, wav, waveform

I'm developing a collaborating music files. I know how to read a file in C# but I don't know how to make "wav form" file' after merging music files.

How would I go about that?

I think these classes would be used:

```
WaveStream;
WaveChannel32;
DirectSoundOut
```

Comment: look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441980/naudio-save-streaming-data-to-wav-file

WaveFileWriter---->>>

Greetings

Comment: Read the file as Byte stream and save it with WaveFileWriter.

Comment: Have a look at this project: http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/